# Making non-nullable class fields not required if they have a default value

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following class:

```
class MarkdownRenderingContextData {
  MarkdownRenderingContextData({
    required this.textSize,
    required this.textStyle
  });
  MarkdownTextSize textSize = MarkdownTextSize.text;
  MarkdownTextStyle textStyle = MarkdownTextStyle.normal;
}
```

What I want is:

- If you don't pass `textStize` and `textStyle`, they have the default value.
- If you pass them, they must not be null.

I'm not being able to do it. Dart is forcing me to add the `required` in the construtor, which is making them mandatory during instanciation and I don't want it. If I make them NOT required (e.g `MarkdownTextSize?`) now I have to check for null during use.

Is there any way around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a default value in the constructor, and make the members `final`:

```
class MarkdownRenderingContextData {
  MarkdownRenderingContextData({
    this.textSize = MarkdownTextSize.text,
    this.textStyle =  MarkdownTextStyle.normal
  });
  final MarkdownTextSize textSize;
  final MarkdownTextStyle textStyle;
}
```